# Spreadsheet to CSV Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I am trying to user powershell to convert an excel spreadsheet to CSV, below is the function I am using:

```
Function ConvertCSV{
    Write-Host "Converting the list to CSV..."
    $sExcelFile=$inputfile
    $sCSVFile="C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\CACL.csv"

    #Get COM Object
    $oExcel = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
    #Should Excel be visible?
    $oExcel.Visible = $true
    #and open excel file
    $oExcelDoc = $oExcel.Workbooks.Open($sExcelFile)

    # Open 1st Worksheet
    $oWorksheet = $oExcelDoc.Worksheets.item(1)
    #Activate, show it
    $oWorksheet.Activate()
    $oExcelDoc.SaveAs($sCSVFile,[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlCSVWindows)

    $oExcelDoc.Close($false)
    Start-Sleep 1
    # Cleanup COM
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($oWorksheet)|out-null
    $oWorksheet=$null
    Start-Sleep 1
    #Cleanup COM
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($oExcelDoc)|out-null
    $oExcelDoc=$null
    #Close Excel
    $oExcel.Quit()
    Start-Sleep 1
    #Cleanup COM
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($oExcel)|out-null
    $oExcel=$null
    [GC]::Collect()
    [GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
}
ConvertCSV
```

However when I run this and it loads the spreadsheet it says that it cannot open "CALC.csv" due to it being corrupted. Below is the error reported by powershell.

> Exception calling "SaveAs" with "2" argument(s): "SaveAs method of Workbook class failed"
>
> At line:17 char:5
>
> $oExcelDoc.SaveAs($sCSVFile,[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::x ...
>    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation

Comment: Doug Finke has an excellent module for  dealing with XLS files.  It includes ConvertFrom-CSV https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/4.0.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is that PowerShell can't expand the %USERNAME% variable.  PowerShell uses a different syntax for accessing environment variable.  In your case, try changing the path from:

```
$sCSVFile="C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\CACL.csv"
```

to:

```
$sCSVFile="$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\CACL.csv"
```

Comment: Or just `$home\desktop\CACL.csv`